# Hide desktop icons for certain mounted volumes

Tags: gnome, mount, icons, fstab, 18.10

I have fixed and removable disks/volumes and they all show an icon on the desktop. I only want the removable mounts shown.

There is a dconf setting to show/hide icons, but it shows/hides all of them. I want to be selective.

An example of a fixed mount from `/etc/fstab`:

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/some-uuid /mnt/Stuff auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

How should I change it?

Comment: one unsual way is to rename the partition lable with .(dot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RZXv.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `x-gvfs-show` mount option:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/some-uuid /mnt/Stuff auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

so it becomes:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/some-uuid /mnt/Stuff auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```